# How to list all directories with the same node using only "ls" and globbing arguments

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, terminal

Prove the link count is correct by listing all the directories that link to 
    it in a single ls(1) command. Your proof will show the inode numbers of 
    all linked directories being the same. This will require ls, some options,
    and some globbing arguments.  Regular globbing arguments are all that is
    required.

I tried using this

```
ls -laiFR ../*q10 |grep 337
```

the links should be 9. it only displays 8 missing the link in the parent directory. Also I am not allowed to use grep. how can i do this? thanks

Comment: What's the directory structure here exactly? Is something like `ls -i ../q10 */..` the answer (where `q10` is the name of the directory in question)?

Comment: it is /home/gaga/q10; there are 7 directories inside of q10.

Comment: `ls -id /home/gaga/q10 /home/gaga/q10/. /home/gaga/q10/*/..`?

Comment: @EtanReisner That works, unless a directory named `/home/gaga/q10/.foo` exists.  Adding `/home/gaga/q10/.?*/..` almost fixes that...but lists `/home` as well.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Good catch. This `/home/gaga/q10/.[!.]*/..` should fix that I think